# How can i calculate the entropy of the region of interest of an RGB image?

Tags: matlab

Sample image:

[image: sample image]

I know how to calculate the entropy of an RGB image.First ,vectorize  the image and finally use it as a parameter of the  entropy() function.

```
image_vector = double(original_RGB_image(:));

entropy_of_the_image = entropy(image_vector);
```

But what should we do to calculate the entropy of the region of interest of image?

I know one approach.Somehow,convert it into a black-white image(white=1) and use the inverse of the black-white image as a parameter of the original RGB image.I think,then the background color will be black .But it doesnot work.The background(sourrounding) became blue(something like that) instead of black? what should i do?
Here is my code...

```
a=imread('ISIC_0000001 w.jpg');
a=imresize(a,[300 300]);
mkr=a;
figure,
imshow(mkr);
im=rgb2gray(a);
level=graythresh(im);
a=im2bw(im,level);
figure,
imshow(a);
mkr(a)=nan;
figure,
imshow(mkr);
```

Comment: It may be useful to simplify your example, ideally create a very simple (artificial) example demonstrating your problem. See [mcve].

Comment: I tried best to explain problem.For that i attached a code for my approach.

Comment: Acctually,i want to "How can i calculate the entropy of the region of interest of an RGB image?"

Comment: So, a lot of the provided code is irrelevant. Please simplify it. It will make it easier to answer and more interesting for later reference.

Comment: ok.I will do it now

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

> I think,then the background color will be black .But it doesnot work.The background(sourrounding) became blue(something like that) instead of black? what should i do?

Check the actual, numeric values in your image matrix first.  If they are in fact 0 or `nan` then the blue you are seeing there is most likely a result of the color map configuration (where numbers are used as a reference to colors in the map).

Another issue here may be related to the mismatch of having three channels in your image (red, green, blue) and only one channel for your black and white image that you are using as a filter layer, or logical indexing matrix.

Assuming that you have your black and white image working so you are getting 1's in the corresponding region of interest in your image, and 0's elsewhere, and you have named this variable `regionOfInterestImage`.  You can calculate the entropy of your red, green, and blue channels of your image, with logical indexing.  The `regionOfInterestImage` however is an NxM matrix however, while your original image is a NxMx3 matrix (x3 for R,G,B).

Let's say you have calculated this matrix of 1's and 0's, where 1's correspond to your region of interest, and called it `regionOfInterestImage` in your code.

As an example using images available with MATLAB:

```
rgbImg = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');

%create a filter layer based on primarily blue pixels:
regionOfInterest = rgbImg(:,:,2)>100 & rgbImg(:,:,1)<100 & rgbImg(:,:,3)<100;
```

Now repeat this region of interest layer for each of your channels so it can be used to access the pixel values in your original image that you want to calculate the entropy of.

```
entropy_of_the_image_region = entropy(rgbImg(repmat(regionOfInterest,1,1,3)));
```

I used `repmat` here to repeat the `regionOfInterest` layer across each channel.  The resulting NxMx3 matrix is then used to index into the original RGB image (`rgbImg`) and obtain the corresponding channel values, as a vector, for processing by `entropy`.